# Can't test my own app using Facebook with android sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on learning about the Facebook sdk with Android and I wanted to test posting on my own wall, and I read on my app's dashboard page that administrators can test apps fully.  My app still doesn't post to my wall though and I feel that it is because it hasn't gone through the approval process (which makes no sense to me because I'm an admin for it).

What gives?

Comment: No it is not because you haven't gone through the approval process. If you are admin you can do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have already used facebook sdk and i used the request class to do this after login. The solution is here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Request/